# Adding hours across the DST transition in moments

Tags: momentjs, dst

I'm trying to create a graph that has a vertical grid line (coming off the X axis) on every 0, 6am, midday and 6pm, using d3. I'm doing this by manually calculating the tick values in momentjs. I calculate the start of the day easily with

```
 firstPoint = momenttz(startDate).startOf('day')
```

And then add 6 hours to it in a loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= days * 24; i += 6) {
    hourTickValues.push(firstPoint.clone().add(i, 'hours'));
}
```

When crossing into or out of daylight saving time I want to keep the lines at the local time of 6am, midday and 6pm. This will mean that twice a year the grid spacing will be different as there are only 5 hours between 12am and 6am going in to DST and 7 hours when coming out.

Momentjs's [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) clearly state that when adding *hours* to a time it does not adjust for daylight saving, but when adding *days* it will. I've also discovered that adding fractional days does not work, it always rounds up to an integer.

So, how can I reliably create a (momentjs) date object for every 6th hour according the DST adjusting clock?

Comment: Did you try using duration? The doc you linked states: _Alternatively, you can use [durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) to add to moments_, so you may have something like: `hourTickValues.push(firstPoint.clone().add(moment.duration({hours: i}));`

Comment: I didn't because within minutes of posing the question I have solved it by manually casting each item to the 6th hour `hourTickValues[everyhourTickValues.length - 1].hours(i % 24);`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually setting each time objects hour after creation.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= days * 24; i += 6) {
    hourTickValues.push(firstPoint.clone().add(i, 'hours'));
    hourTickValues[hourTickValues length - 1].hours(i % 24);
}
```